# call static method on value which is returned from static method

Tags: php

Assume we have a static method `getModel`, which returns a fully qualified namespace to a class which also has a static method `find`. How to call the static method from the returned namespace?

```
self::getModel($modelName)::find($id);
```

This throws a syntax error in php complaining about `:`.

You can ofc write:

```
$temp = self::getModel($modelName);
$temp::find($id);
```

But thats not what I want

// EDIT: Better example

```
class A{

    public static function getSomeStuff(){
        self::getModel('MyModel')::find($id);
    }

    public static function getModel($modelName){
        return $GLOBALS['somewhere'][$modelName];
        // which is something like
        // MyApp\Models\MyModel
    }

}



// The Model in another file
namespace \MyApp\Models;

class MyModel{
    public static function find($id){
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: `${self::getModel($modelName)}::find($id);` ?

Comment: @Darren I figured that, too. But this turns out to be: `Fatal error: Class name must be a valid object or a string`

Comment: Can you show the code of these classes in basic form ?

Comment: Here's a fiddle, from what I understand: https://eval.in/601600, or maybe this: https://eval.in/601604

Comment: *"which returns an object which also has a static method"* ~ this statement simply cannot be true. An object by definition is an instance and therefore cannot have static methods. What **exactly** does `getModel` return?

Comment: tried to make it more clear

Comment: So once returned, what exactly is `return $GLOBALS['somewhere'][$modelName];` ?

Comment: Another update for that. A namespace to a class.

Comment: Your current code and the value example `\MyApp\Models\MyModel` does not correlate with the error message. php clearly states that it's not a string there.

Comment: When I do this, I get a ParseError about unexpected `::`. If i add brackets like already mentioned it comes to the Fatal Error

Comment: Not really. Because `$GLOBALS['somewhere'][$modelName]::find($id)` IS working

Comment: What **EXACTLY** is in `$GLOBALS['somewhere']['MyModel']`? Not *"something like"*. Not *"a namespace to a class"*. Show **precisely** where you assign a value to `$GLOBALS['somewhere']['MyModel']`

Comment: Its that what you get when you evaluate `\MyApp\Models\MyModel::class` which is certainly a String.

Comment: FYI, `::class` omits the leading \